# derivation of equation in kalaith's "weiner and kalman filtering" book

Tags: kalman-filter

Hi: Asked this question ( at the link below ) on the dsp list a few years ago and it didn't really get answered to a point where it clicked for me. Lately, I've been reading the same book again and I'm starting to think that it's really important to understand this approximation because , if one can understand this, it's kind of the basis for how weiner derives his relations. If anyone can explain how the approximation works, it's really appreciated. Note that my four sub-questions can be disregarded. The question is really just that don't understand the discrete approximation behind the formula is using at all. Thanks a lot.

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/31277/is-there-a-name-for-this-smoothing-formula

Comment: I think the question you are linking to seems to be describing [zero order hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold).

Comment: Hi and thanks. Someone mentioned that in the answers from the dsp community and I understand the link. It's the initial time domain expression that I find totally befuddling. For example, why would zero order hold be a sum in the time domain ? Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Hi: I looked at the wiki  again and I'm starting to see some kind of connection between the use of rect and the formula that I don't follow so I'll study the link more closely and try to figure it out. Maybe I didn't follow the link as well as I thought when it was recommended on dsp.  Still if anyone wants to shed light, it's still appreciated. Thanks a lot for pointing to link.